# Extremely slow api calls caused by {method 'next_event' of 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.SegregatedCall' objects}

Tags: python, grpc, cython, google-ads-api

I am utilizing the python client library for the Google Ads API. Alls has been working as expected and all of a sudden began running extremely slow when running locally on my Mac. Ran the cProfile tool and found that this 'next_event' method from gRPC has started taking between 8-10secs per call.

Even basic usage of the API (i.e. GAQL to pull in campaign names) returns the same latency issue.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    8.123    8.123    8.126    8.126 {method 'next_event' of 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.SegregatedCall' objects}
```

Have tried various versions of Python and the google-ads and gRPC packages. Others have ran this same code from the same repo/branch on their machines and do not experience this issue so I am trying to determine what about my environment/Mac is causing this issue.

Comment: hi, Did you manage to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @PabloIglesias Nope

Comment: I experienced this and the issue in my case turned out to be related to DNS, which I could see when I enabled [trace logs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/19f1b39829259f0f46ec8bd27c2208c7dfa4812d/TROUBLESHOOTING.md). Setting `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native` worked around the problem for me.